# Why is the size of Option<bool> equal to 1?

Tags: rust, size

On [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ae5872bfd6beffe5e84c6469f506631f), the size of an `Option<bool>` is 1. Is rust packing the option information into the bool itself? So the Option represents the 3 possible states: `None`, `Some(false)`, `Some(true)`?

```rust
use std::mem::size_of;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", size_of::<Option<bool>>()); // 1
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. This is called niche optimization. `bool` has a *niche* of 7 bits (7 unused bits), and we pack `Option::None` into those.

You can inspect the bytes ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f9ef108b68f1cc54cf0feefaa2a0401b)):

```rust
fn main() {
    fn print_bytes(v: Option<bool>) {
        println!("{:08b}", unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<Option<bool>, u8>(v) });
    }
    print_bytes(Some(false));
    print_bytes(Some(true));
    print_bytes(None);
}
```

```
00000000
00000001
00000010
```

You can see we use the second bit to indicate `None`.

Note that as said in the comment by @Cerberus, the memory layout is not guaranteed for `#[repr(rust)]` types and one should not rely on it.

Comment: Note however that the exact implementation is not guaranteed, so one should not check this bit manually and relying on the result for correctness.